# Last Element in my Array is a large number that I never inputted

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, arraylist, visual-c++

I'm storing the results of a "Dice Roll" in an Array.
Everything seems to be working fine, except the last value of the Array is a ╠ (-858993460)?
I tried troubleshooting and its happening right in the beginning and I don't know why.

```
const int QDice = 3;
int Domain = 6 * QDice;
int CD[6 * QDice]{};
do
{
    cout << "Array CD[" << i << "] = " << CD[i] << "\n";
    i++;
} while (i <= Domain);
```

This yields:

```
Array CD[1] = 0
...
Array CD[18] = -858993460
```

Everything is fine accept the last element.

Comment: Array indexes in C++ are 0 based, so the `Domain` elements of the `CD` array run from `CD[0]` to `CD[Domain - 1]`. The last iteration of the `while (i <= Domain)` loop runs with `i = Domain` and `CD[i]` reads one past the end of the array, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ array index starts from 0, so the array `CD[]` range is from 1 to 17. When the `Domain` becomes 18, the array is out of bounds. I suggest that you could modify the code to the following code.

```
    do
    {
        cout << "Array CD[" << i << "] = " << CD[i] << "\n";
        i++;
    } while (i <= Domain - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66687238/616815), you're assuming 1-based indexing while c++ arrays use 0-based indexing. This means index 18 is out-of-bounds, i.e., it is past the end of the array. But why that does that negative number show up?

First of all, when an out-of-bounds condition exists, the program exhibits undefined behaviour. That means the program can do literally anything, whether it's what you intended or not. In practice, though, the program will often assume that arrays are large enough for the index being used. So in your case, it will look up the memory where index 18 ought to be (as if the array were large enough for that), and then try to interpret the bytes it finds there as some meaningful value.

Now, as a general rule, memory can have any value at all, unless you set it to something specific. By initializing your array, you set the memory for each array element to a definite value (0). But just past the end of the array is memory that you haven't set, so those bytes could be anything. In your case, they just happen to be set in such a way that they are interpreted as the -858993460, but that could just as well be any other value.